# Create procedure to verify if driver is mechanic

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor, verify

i got a employee, driver and mechanic table. A driver cannot be a mechanic vice versa and i need to create a procedure VERIFY to verify this statement. currently i have this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VERIFY IS
ENAME VARCHAR(25);
MESSAGE VARCHAR(50) := 'OK';
CHECK1 BOOLEAN := FALSE;

DRIVERNUM TRKEMPLOYEE.E#%TYPE;
MECHANICNUM TRKEMPLOYEE.E#%TYPE;

CURSOR DRIVERNUM_CURSOR IS SELECT E# FROM TRKDRIVER;
CURSOR MECHANICNUM_CURSOR IS SELECT E# FROM TRKMECHANIC;

BEGIN
OPEN DRIVERNUM_CURSOR;
LOOP
FETCH DRIVERNUM_CURSOR INTO DRIVERNUM;

    OPEN MECHANICNUM_CURSOR;
    LOOP
    FETCH MECHANICNUM_CURSOR INTO MECHANICNUM;

        IF MECHANICNUM_CURSOR%NOTFOUND THEN
        EXIT;
        END IF;

        IF (DRIVERNUM = MECHANICNUM) THEN 
        SELECT NAME INTO ENAME FROM TRKEMPLOYEE WHERE E# = DRIVERNUM;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE#: ' || TO_CHAR(DRIVERNUM));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEENAME: ' || ENAME);
        CHECK1 := TRUE;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE MECHANICNUM_CURSOR;

    IF DRIVERNUM_CURSOR%NOTFOUND THEN
    EXIT;
    END IF;

END LOOP;
CLOSE DRIVERNUM_CURSOR;


IF CHECK1 = FALSE THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MESSAGE);
END IF;



EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NULL');

END;
/


EXECUTE VERIFY;
```

It warned me saying procedure created with compilation errors. Please help thanks !
And also in stated in my code, i need it to show me a message 'OK' if there is no driver that is also registered as a mechanic.

Comment: What are yuo tryying to accomplish? Find drivers that are in the mechanics-table? That can be done with a single `SELECT`, no need for all this. I am not even going to ask why you have the seperate tables...

Comment: That is not a procedure for SQL Server. That is Oracle PL/SQL. Which DBMS are you actually using?

Comment: Yes @oerkelens i know i can do it with a select statement but i need to run this umpteen times. that is why i need a procedure. Not ?

Comment: Then why not put that simple select in a procedure?
Also, if yuo need to run this so often, i would suggest a constraint on your database so that users can not add data that violates your business rules. Then you don't need to think of a way to continously clean up :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly complicated. To find out those who are both mechanics and drivers, loop over this query:

```
SELECT d.E#, e.NAME
FROM TRKDRIVER d
JOIN TRKMECHANUC m on m.E# = d.E#
JOIN TRKEMOYEE e on e.E# = d.E#
```

The results are identical to what your many loops, tests and queries produce.

Comment: Yes @bohemian that is a good query but do u have any idea why do i get a compilation error ?